# Mongoid, query get embedded field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

How execute query on collection associate with embedded

```
class SaleInvoice
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

   embeds_many :sale_invoice_lines, :order => 'numlig ASC'


  field :code, type: String
end

class SaleInvoiceLine
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  belongs_to :element, primary_key: :code, foreign_key: :codeelem

  field :numlig, type: Integer
  field :codeelem, type: String

end

class Element
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Tree

  has_many :sale_invoice_lines, primary_key: :code, foreign_key: :codeelem

  field :code, type: String
end
```

the query

```
  SaleInvoice.only(:_id,:code, "sale_invoice_lines.code","sale_invoice_lines.numlig")
     .where("sale_invoice_lines.codeelem" => {"$in" => Element.all.map {|e| e.code}}).all
```

How get data sale_invoice_lines.code and sale_invoice_lines.codeelem ?

I try this

```
  s[0].sale_invoice_sales[0].code
```

But i have got following error

```
  undefined method `sale_invoice_sales' for #<SaleInvoice:0x56447526>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
s = SaleInvoice.only(...).where(...).all
```

That means that `s` is an array of `SaleInvoice` instances. In `SaleInvoice` you have:

```
class SaleInvoice
  embeds_many :sale_invoice_lines, :order => 'numlig ASC'
end
```

so your can access the embedded lines through:

```
s.first.sale_invoice_lines
```

and such.

Comment: Oh no... sale_invoice_lines and not sale_invoice_sales... I'm going to sleep... Thank you for your Answer